# Prove the inequality for $\Delta\geq 2$ if $N\geq 3\Delta \log_2 \Delta$ then $N^\Delta+1<2^N$

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality

Does anyone have the idea to solve this inequality  for $\Delta\geq 2$ if $N\geq 3\Delta \log_2 \Delta$ then $N^\Delta+1<2^N$?

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: I move all the terms to right had side, and set a function try to prove that it is positive. But I got stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By taking the logarithm on both side, it is equivalent to prove:
$$\frac{\ln(N)}{N} \leq \frac1{\Delta}\frac{\ln(2^N -1)}{N}$$
If $N \geq e$, the left side is decreasing. The left side is always increasing. Let $\alpha = 3 \Delta \log_2(\Delta) \geq e$. Then, for all $N\geq \alpha$:
$$\frac{\ln(N)}{N} \leq \frac{\ln(\alpha)}{\alpha}$$
and 
$$\frac1{\Delta}\frac{\ln(2^N -1)}{N} \geq \frac1{\Delta}\frac{\ln(2^{\alpha} -1)}{\alpha}$$
It remains to prove that  :
$$\frac{\ln(\alpha)}{\alpha} < \frac1{\Delta}\frac{\ln(2^{\alpha} -1)}{\alpha}$$
wich is equivalent to :
$$\alpha^{\Delta} +1 < 2^{\alpha}$$
The left side is : 
$$\alpha^{\Delta} +1 = \big(3 \Delta \log_2(\Delta)\big)^{\Delta} + 1$$
The right side is :
$$2^{\alpha} = \Delta^{3\Delta}$$
The following is not really rigorous, but I am too lazy now to transform it into rigorous proof. For large $\Delta$ the inequality with $\alpha$ is true. By plotting the function, one can check it is true for  $\Delta \geq 2$.
[image: 1]
 The result follows.

Comment: For a fixed $\Delta$, l know the inequality is true for large $N$. But how to handle when $N$ is small?

Comment: I think you can study the variation of each function. Or, you can just plot the functions.

Answer (score 0):

We will denote the binary log as $\lg$ and the natural log as $\ln$ in this solution. We will instead show that for $N \geq 3 \Delta \lg \Delta$, the inequality $N^{\Delta} < 2^{N}$ holds. The math is slightly messier for the inequality you are trying to prove, but the steps are the same.

To do this, we will first show that if $N = N_0(\Delta) = 3 \Delta \lg \Delta$, then $N^{\Delta} \leq 2^N$. To do so, just exponentiate both sides of the first equation  (with base $2$):
$$\Delta^{3\Delta} = 2^{N_0}$$
However, we note that for $\Delta \geq 2$, we have
$$N_0 = 3 \Delta \cdot \lg \Delta \leq \Delta^3$$
This can be seen in many ways; for example, one can take the ratio of the left-hand side to the right-hand side and see it goes to zero. You can also note that the right-hand side grows cubically, while the left-hand side grows linearithmically. This inequality implies that
$$N_0^{\Delta} = (3\Delta \lg \Delta)^\Delta \leq (\Delta^3)^{\Delta} = 2^{N_0}$$

To show that $N^{\Delta} \leq 2^N$ for all $N > 3 \Delta \log_2 \Delta = N_0$, consider the log of the ratio of the two sides: 
$$r = \lg \left(\frac{2^N}{N^\Delta}\right) = N - \Delta \log N$$
We can see that the ratio is monotonically increasing in $N$ whenever $N \geq 3 \Delta \lg \Delta$, as its derivative
$$\frac{dr}{dN} = 1 - \frac{\Delta}{N \ln 2} \geq 1 - \frac{1}{3\ln 2 \lg \Delta} = 1 - \frac{1}{3 \ln \Delta} >0$$
whenever $N \geq 3 \Delta \log \Delta$. As the log of the ratio is increasing for $N \geq 3 \Delta \log \Delta$, the ratio itself is an increasing function for this interval as well. But we showed that for $N = N_0 = 3 \Delta \log \Delta$, $r(N_0) \geq 1$, so it follows that $r(N) > 1$ for $N > N_0$. This proves the assertion.